# How does Android handle alarms set for the past

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

In my application I want to trigger a recurring alarm at about a specified time to check for some conditions and notify the user if necessary.

I'm using the following code to schedule the alarm:

```
Calendar cal = ...;
...

mAlarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mAlarmIntent);
```

I now noticed (because I accidentially had the wrong day in `cal`) that the alarm would be triggered right away if `cal` was some date/time in the past.

So let's say it is `2016-09-20 18:00:00` and I schedule the alarm for `2016-09-20 17:00:00`. I'd get a notification right away (or a couple of seconds after scheduling the alarm). This does not happen if I schedule the alarm for a future time like `2016-09-20 18:15:00`.

So my questions are:

1. Will Android always catch up on the missed alarm?
2. The alarm is scheduled to repreat daily. Will it then repeat at `17:00:00` tomorrow or will it be at `18:00:00`, because that was when the alarm was last triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will Android always catch up on the missed alarm?

if the set time is in past then android trigger alarm as soon as possible. [check the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> The alarm is scheduled to repreat daily. Will it then repeat at
>   17:00:00 tomorrow or will it be at 18:00:00, because that was when the
>   alarm was last triggered?

Next time it will be triggered on time

**Additional Info** : if the use clear app data or forced close your app from application manager then alarm won't trigger until user open your app again plus reboot can also cause this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I hoped. Is there any link to the docs where I can read up on this?

Comment: check the official docs link , it will give you all details you want Sir @Thorsten Dittmar

Comment: I do listen to "boot finished" broadcasts, so alarms will be restarted properly.